# binding to children's controllers properties

Tags: ember.js

I want to bind parent (arrayController) property with children (itemController). The binding works only when I'm setting the properites in childController like this.set('foo', property), instead using computed properties.

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  numberOfAllLetters: (function() {
    return this.getEach('lettersNo').reduce(function(prev, curr){
      return prev + curr
    });
  }).property('@each.lettersNo'),

  numberOfAllLetters2: (function() {
    return this.getEach('length2').reduce(function(prev, curr) {
      return prev + curr;
    })
  }).property('@each.length2')

});

// child
App.WordController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  lettersNo: (function() { 
    length = this.get('name').length;
    // why only through 'set' the arrayController binds properly?
    // if in parent controller I bind to '@each.length2', it works good. but why?
    this.set('length2', length); 
    return this.get('name').length;
  }).property('name')
});
```

handlebars:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">

  <ul>
  {{#each word in model itemController="word"}}
    <li>{{input value=word.name}}</li> letters: 
    {{word.lettersNo}}
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
  Total letters:{{numberOfAllLetters}} <br/> <!-- doesnt work -->
  Total letters2:{{numberOfAllLetters2}} <br/> <!-- works -->

</script>
```

I am wondering if I am missing something and why i cannot use the same property in child's template, child's controller and binded to parent's controller.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/licancabur/de1k7jcb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `Ember.ObjectController` and `Ember.ArrayController` [will be deprecated in future](https://gist.github.com/Kuzirashi/7f6016e426005146f593) so it's not recommended to use them if you want upgrade your Ember version. So I came up with solution that gets rid of `Ember.ObjectController` and is working:

```
App.Word = Ember.Object.extend({
    lettersNo: (function() {
      console.log('lettersNo invoked')
    length = this.get('name').length;
    console.log('length change', length);

    return length
  }).property('name')
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return [
        App.Word.create({
            id: 1,
            name: 'one'
        }),
        App.Word.create({
            id: 2,
            name: 'two'
        }),
        App.Word.create({
            id: 3,
            name: 'three'
        }),

    ];
  } 
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  numberOfAllLetters: (function() {
    return this.getEach('lettersNo').reduce(function(prev, curr){
      return prev + curr
    });
  }).property('@each.lettersNo'),
});
```

Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">

    <ul>
        {{#each word in model}}
            <li>{{input value=word.name}}</li> letters: 
            {{word.lettersNo}}
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
    Total letters: {{numberOfAllLetters}} <br/>

</script>
```

[Working JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/de1k7jcb/3/)

How I managed to solve it? You were mentioning that you use `WordController` only in your template - when iterating over words collection(`model`). Your `IndexController` didn't know that `model` has any additional behaviour, so `@each.lettersNo` simply didn't exist for controller. However, when `Ember.Object` - `App.Word` was created - both template and `IndexController` knew it has computed property `lettersNo`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer - that is very interesting. I was trying to find some info about Ember.ArrayController and Ember.ObjectController deprecations - could you write where did you read about it?